# Installing Jupiter on Python 3.8 throws exceptions

Tags: python, jupyter

*
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-53f7fpg4\pywinpty\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-53f7fpg4\pywinpty\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-53f7fpg4\pywinpty\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-53f7fpg4\pywinpty\
    Complete output (161 lines):
    Compiling C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Plex\Scanners.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Plex\Actions.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Compiler\Scanning.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Compiler\Visitor.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Runtime\refnanny.pyx because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Compiler\FusedNode.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Tempita_tempita.py because it changed.
    [1/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.py
    [2/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Compiler\FusedNode.py
    [3/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Compiler\Scanning.py
    [4/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Compiler\Visitor.py
    [5/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Plex\Actions.py
    [6/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Plex\Scanners.py
    [7/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Runtime\refnanny.pyx
    [8/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\Cython\Tempita_tempita.py
    Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
    warning: no files found matching 'Doc*'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython\Debugger\Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython\Debugger\Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython\Utility'
    warning: no files found matching 'pyximport\README'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 489, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
        return self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
    IndexError: list index out of range

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 158, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
    self.build()
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 84, in run
    _build_ext.run(self)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 205, in build_extension
    _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
    objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 360, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
    vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
    return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 843, in __init__
    self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 485, in __init__
    self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 492, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
    raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\setup.py", line 228, in <module>
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
    raise
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-5vh4nmuz\Cython-0.29.15\setup.py", line 228, in <module>
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Kiro_Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-53f7fpg4\pywinpty\setup.py", line 68, in <module>
    setup(
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
    resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "c:\users\kiro_eli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1146, in run_setup
    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
*

This is the error/ exceptions which i get and I cant figure out what the remedy is?

Any thoughts ?

Comment: What command are you using to install jupyter? Is this the default python installation or one you've installed?

Comment: I used   pip install jupyter --user.
As I am new to python and programming altogether , I don't quite get what you meant by your second question.  If you are asking where did i get the python release, I got it from the official site and the version is 3.8.1 . Currently I am attending a Python course and I hit my first snag obviously :) .

Comment: Some machines come with a built-in installation that certain functions depend on, which could be part of the issue. If this is one that you installed, modifying the instance by installing packages isn't a huge concern. It's for background information. `pip install <package>` doesn't always point to the python you think it does, and it can be better to use `python -m pip install <package>` where the `python` specification will make sure you're using that pip, specifically

Comment: But I think really the issue is right at the end of your stack trace: `Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the stacktrace it tells you what to do:

```py
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: 
   Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. 
    Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": 
    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```